# Recompile with -Xlint

Tags: java

After writing a long GUI program and getting the right result in the eclipse the most horrible error is to run seam program in the terminal and get freak out by seeing this error:

```
Note: ./au/edu/uow/UserInterface/UserInterface.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I have been searching before to solve this problem. The solution was to recompile it with another version of compiler.

```
javac -source 1.4 File.java
```

or

```
   javac   Xlint File.java
```

Why this warning happens? If it is because of using deprecated functions, is there anyway to find the problem. To not happen again!

Comment: ...so, what did compiling it with `-Xlint:unchecked` tell you?

Comment: @nneonneo by compiling any of above codes with javac the problem will be solve! but i'm going to send my code to some one, and i afraid they again face with this warning!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first time I compile my code with

```
  javac   Xlint File.java
```

This warning is not happening again.

Answer (score 1):

This resolves my issue...

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this at the beginning of the class:
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
to ignore the warnings and see where the problem is.